# Neo4j webadmin stats showing also nodes from other database on PC

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

Using Neo4j 2.1.5 database client on one PC which I connect using SSH tunnel. On this PC is also other project running Neo4j. When I go to my database using localhost:7474/browser, on left panel are shown labels of nodes and relationships which are not in my database but in that other running on that PC. When I run script of count it returns 0 as count.

When I go to localhost:7474/webadmin in stats there are over 3M nodes and 2.5M relationships but my database is clear. So it is showing stats from my project and that other project together. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

When you clear your database, i.e. delete all nodes and relationships, node labels and relationship types won't clear. It's definitely not showing stats from another project.

Please clear the database that should be clear by removing its graph.db directory and try again.

Comment: Yes this should work, but it is quite uncomfortable. I know why this stats are showing. In past there was this 2 projects in one database somehow and now they are split to 2 separate but, in my remains informations from that other project. Anyway, is there a way how to export all my data in database then clear whole database and then import it?

Comment: I wrote a tool that can help you do that: https://github.com/jexp/store-utils/tree/21 It copies data from one store to another and allows you to skip labels, properties and rel-types.